# JMeter HTTP Raw Request error 400 Bad Request

Tags: jmeter

Is there anything I might be missing from this request?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't know as we don't have any idea how the request is supposed to look like. You need to use a sniffer tool like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) or [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) in order to capture the request coming from i.e your browser and compare it with the request generated by JMeter.

Once you will b/e sending the same requests you will be getting the same response. [HTTP Status Code 400 - Bad Request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400) means that the request you're sending is syntactically incorrect.

Most probably you miss [Content-Disposition header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition)

---

P.S. Is there any specific reason for using HTTP Raw Request instead of "normal" [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler? You can even record the file upload event using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html) assuming that you copy your `bigPDF.pdf` file to "bin" folder of your JMeter installation during the recording. Check out [Recording File Uploads with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter/) article for more details.

Comment: Yep that was it, the problem here is that I can't actually upload in chunks using that HTTP Request Sampler simply because the web app uses resumable.js, so even when all the parameters are there (resumableChunkSize,resumableIdentifier, etc) the file on the other side does not join together for some reason. So I was trying to use this thing except it also didn't work since it's not properly "chunking" the file